# Как создать такой генератор картинок?

Tags: javascript, html5, canvas, html5-canvas

Нужно создать генератор картинок на canvas, который будет выводить примерно такое:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

тут допустим фон и два вида камней.
Формы камней буду рисовать вручную.

Как создать генератор чтобы камни были разных размеров и чтобы они не ложились друг на друга?

Comment: Это тайловые изображения, поищите в сторону "how to tile image" или что-то подобное